# Find elements with specific order in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Find the elements with order $4$ in the group $(\mathbb{Z}/525\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, where $(\mathbb{Z}/525\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is the multiplicative group of the units in $(\mathbb{Z}/525\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Then？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what Tobias Kildetoft was hinting at:

So $525 = 5^2·3·7$. By the chinese remainder theorem, $ℤ/525ℤ \cong ℤ/25ℤ × ℤ/3ℤ × ℤ/7ℤ$. This isomorphism restricts to the unit groups of those rings, that is $$(ℤ/525ℤ)^×  \cong (ℤ/25ℤ)^× × (ℤ/3ℤ)^× × (ℤ/7ℤ)^×.$$
Now, do you have an idea what you could do next to find an element on the left side of order four?

Comment: Can you give me more details for the case of $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: What do you mean? An element of order four in $ℤ/25ℤ$ is an element whose square is $-1$ in $ℤ/25ℤ$. That shouldn’t be too hard to find.